# how to solve error "could not deserialize" when trying to fetch/read data from two database tables using DTO pattern using spring data jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, dto

I am trying to read data from 5 tables that share relationship in a database with Springboot using Spring Data Jpa with the DTO pattern. I put the two tables into one entity class using @Table and @SecondaryTable annotations. However when I try to fetch the data with postman using a GET request, I get an error that says "could not serialize". Please help point me to the right direction if you can, I have been on this the whole day and I have a short deadline. Thanks in advance.

here is the postgresql table ERD:

[image: erd for the postgresql tables I am working with]

here is the error log below:

```
2020-08-21 15:55:04.411 ERROR 6672 --- [nio-8008-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2763) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:874) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3087) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1851) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1779) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1752) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1600) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:743) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1006) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:962) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2813) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2640) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.controller.AuditorStampDutyReportController.findAll(AuditorStampDutyReportController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.controller.AuditorStampDutyReportController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5f876fba.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.controller.AuditorStampDutyReportController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8f302d7f.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.security.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
```

this is my entity class that combines both tables(auditor_stamp_duty_report & deed of assignment tables)

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="auditor_stamp_duty_report")
@SecondaryTable(name="deed_of_assignment")
public class AuditorStampDutyReport implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private  Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_of_tax_payer_organization", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Organization organization;

    @Column(name="tin_of_tax_payer_organization")
    private Long tin_of_tax_payer_organization;

    @Column(name="period_covered")
    private String period_covered;

    @Column(name="date_of_transaction")
    private LocalDate date_of_transaction;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_of_duty_payer_or_bank", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Banks banks;

    @Column(name="tin_of_duty_payer_or_bank")
    private Long tin_of_duty_payer_or_bank;

    @Column(name="address_of_duty_payer_or_bank")
    private String address_of_duty_payer_or_bank;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="instrument_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Instruments instruments;

    @Column(name="assessment_number")
    private Long assessment_number;

    @Column(name="receipt_number")
    private String receipt_number;

    @Column(name="consideration")
    private Double consideration;

    @Column(name="rate")
    private Double rate;

    @Column(name="amount_payable")
    private Double amount_payable;

    @Column(name="amount_paid")
    private Double amount_paid;

    @Column(name="balance")
    private Double balance;

    @Column(name="penalty")
    private Double penalty;

    @Column(name= "outstanding")
    private Double outstanding;

    @Column(name = "remarks")
    private String remarks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    @Column(name="state_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
    private State state;

    @Column(name="lga_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
    private Lga lga;

    @Column(name="ward", table="deed_of_assignment")
    private Long ward;

    @Column(name="description_of_location", table="deed_of_assignment")
    private String description_of_location;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="author_stamp_duty_report_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignment;


}
```

here is my DTO layer

```
import com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.entity.Lga;
import com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.entity.State;
import lombok.Data;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
public class AuditorStampDutyReportDto {

    private  Long id;

    private Long id_of_tax_payer_organization;

    private Long id_of_duty_payer_or_bank;

    private Long tin_of_tax_payer_organization;

    private String period_covered;

    private LocalDate date_of_transaction;

    private Long tin_of_duty_payer_or_bank;

    private String address_of_duty_payer_or_bank;

    private Long instrument_id;

    private Long assessment_number;

    private String receipt_number;

    private Double consideration;

    private Double rate;

    private Double amount_payable;

    private Double amount_paid;

    private Double balance;

    private Double penalty;

    private Double outstanding;

    private String remarks;

    private Long user_profile_id;

    private Long state_id;

    private Long lga_id;

    private Long ward;

    private String description_of_location;

    private Long author_stamp_duty_report_id;
}
```

here is my Service layer where I use logic to try to fetch data from the database table

```
package com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.services;



//relevant imports 


@Data
@Service
public class AuditorStampDutyReportService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuditorStampDutyReportService.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private AuditorStampDutyReportRepository auditorStampDutyReportRepository;


    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    public AuditorStampDutyReportDto entityToDto(AuditorStampDutyReport report) {

        AuditorStampDutyReportDto dto = new AuditorStampDutyReportDto();

        dto.setId(report.getId());
        Organization organization = report.getOrganization();
        dto.setId_of_tax_payer_organization(organization.getId());
        dto.setTin_of_tax_payer_organization(report.getTin_of_tax_payer_organization());
        dto.setPeriod_covered(report.getPeriod_covered());
        dto.setDate_of_transaction(report.getDate_of_transaction());

        Banks banks= report.getBanks();
        dto.setId_of_duty_payer_or_bank(banks.getId());
        dto.setTin_of_duty_payer_or_bank(report.getTin_of_duty_payer_or_bank());
        dto.setAddress_of_duty_payer_or_bank(report.getAddress_of_duty_payer_or_bank());

        Instruments instruments = report.getInstruments();
        dto.setInstrument_id(instruments.getId());
        dto.setAssessment_number(report.getAssessment_number());
        dto.setReceipt_number(report.getReceipt_number());
        dto.setConsideration(report.getConsideration());
        dto.setRate(report.getRate());
        dto.setAmount_payable(report.getAmount_payable());
        dto.setAmount_paid(report.getAmount_paid());
        dto.setBalance(report.getBalance());
        dto.setPenalty(report.getPenalty());
        dto.setOutstanding(report.getOutstanding());
        dto.setRemarks(report.getRemarks());

        UserProfile userProfile =report.getUserProfile();
        dto.setUser_profile_id(userProfile.getId());

        State state = report.getState();
        dto.setState_id(state.getId());

        Lga lga = report.getLga();
        dto.setLga_id(lga.getId());

        dto.setWard(report.getWard());

        dto.setDescription_of_location(report.getDescription_of_location());

        DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignment=report.getDeedOfAssignment();
        dto.setAuthor_stamp_duty_report_id(deedOfAssignment.getId());
        return dto;
    }
```

This is my controller layer below...

```
//relevant imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/auditors_report")
public class AuditorStampDutyReportController {

    @Autowired
    public AuditorStampDutyReportService auditorStampDutyReportService;

    @Autowired
    public AuditorStampDutyReportRepository auditorStampDutyRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/find/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<AuditorStampDutyReportDto> findAll(){
        List <AuditorStampDutyReport> findAll = auditorStampDutyRepository.findAll();
        return auditorStampDutyReportService.entityToDto(findAll);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing `@ManyToOne` annotations on the following two properties which are now treated as serializable types as the stack trace suggests:

```
@Column(name="state_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
private State state;

@Column(name="lga_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
private Lga lga;
```

These should probably be

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="state_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
private State state;

@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="lga_id", table="deed_of_assignment")
private Lga lga;
```